# EF 4.3 Code First one-to-one relationship when using an existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I have two tables in my database which have a one-to-one relationship. I want to access them with EF using the code first approach. I have written the POCO classes like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
    public bool? Male { get; set; }
}
```

And also I described the relationships between that classes in the OnModelCreating as explained [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/19/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx). So that's how looks:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasKey(x => x.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
    HasOptional(u => u.Profile).
    WithRequired();
```

But when I run the application I'm getting this exception when trying to access the User tables:

> Invalid column name "User_Id"

Although when I let EF create a new database on its own with these two tables, it creates a database that has **the same structure** as mine and it works.

I was using EF 4.3 (I tried 4.2 too) and MS SQL 2008. What am I doing wrong? I can't believe that it's a bug of Entity Framework.

Comment: "Code First" means you don't have a datastore yet. :)

Comment: @rfmodulator, Well yes:) But in real life things are not so easy. So you think that EF wasn't created/tested for the purpose I am trying to use it?

Comment: Again, "Code First" means you define your classes first, then the framework creates the underlying datastore schema. EF is perfectly capable of using an existing database, I was merely pointing out that what you're doing is not(!!!) "Code First.

Comment: rfmodulator is right - code first is not better solution in that case. Try to use Model First approach.

Comment: You actually can do what @Z_Core is trying to do, but you need to get into Migrations: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, guys, for your help. I realized that code first is not the way I should go and I have chosen the database first approach. [With the POCO templates for the Entity Framework.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

EF requires that one-to-one columns both share the same primary key, and that there is a referential FK between the two.

If this is the case, you can use the Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1 to reverse engineer your database as a Code First model.

You can find it here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d